# NestJS MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given when TypeOrmModule is reading ormconfig.js file

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am running a Nest JS application in development mode. The app module is like below. I kept the configuration details inside the `ormconfig.js` so that both `TypeormModule` and Typeorm CLI would be able to do the migrations.

```js
@Module({
  import: [
   TypeormModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
```

ormconfig.js :

```js
module.exports = {
  "type": "sqlite",
  "database": "db.sqlite",
  "entities": ["**/*.entity.js"],
  "synchronize": false
}
```

I am running the development server using `cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch` command. I am getting the error :

> Wrong driver "undefined" given. Supported drivers are: "aurora-mysql", "aurora-postgres", "sqlite" etc.

I clearly know the error here i.e., Typeorm is failing to pick up configuration details from the `ormconfig.js` file. Other solutions like adding `Typeorm.forRootAsync` and loading config details directly in  `Typeorm.forRoot({...configDetails})` are out of scope here.

Do I need to do any specific configuration so that Typeorm would pick the config details from `ormconfig.js`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved by using the below steps.

1. Pass the config object that is exported from `ormconfig.js` as the parameter of `TypeormModule.forRoot()` like below inside the `appmodule` file.

   ```
    const dbConfig = require("PATH_TO_YOUR_CONFIG_FILE"); 
    TypeormModule.forRoot(dbConfig)
   ```
2. If it still doesn't work, Delete the `dist` folder and re-run the `yarn start` command. The cache issue will be resolved with this step.